# Rails caches_page is not reading instance variables and throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, page-caching

I am trying to implement caching in rails and wants to cache whole homepage. So far the quickiest way is to use `cache_page :home` method in controller but it doesn't seems to work even once. This is my `home` method.

```
  def home 
    @banners = BannerUpload.order('series').with_attached_image
    img = ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("share-meta.png")

    @sections = Section.includes(:homepage_items).where(active: true).order('position')
    @testimonials = Testimonial.where(status: true)
  end
```

this is the error I am getting:

`undefined method each_with_index for nil:NilClass` for `@banners` object, means query is not hitting even at first time.

I could not find any article on this issue as well. I have tried setting different stores but no help:

`config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store`
or
`config.cache_store = :memory_store` etc

**EDIT**:

I got it solved myself. Actually I am not aware of the fact that page caching is not included by default in rails. So I had to include it with gem 'actionpack-page_caching' after that it worked fine.

Comment: I don't see how caching could cause a nil error - are you sure your page works without caching?

Comment: Late to the party but couldn't you just use `fresh_when`, https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#conditional-get-support . This basically is for static pages that don't change much. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ConditionalGet.html#method-i-fresh_when

Answer (score 0):

Like you are saying: Query is not hitting even at first time.
So it looks like `@banners` is nil and you want to call `each_with_index` on it, this has nothing to do with caching.
In your view you can first check if `@banners` is not nil and then call `each_with_index` on it. Your cache will work if you fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved myself.
Actually I am not aware of the fact that page caching is not included by default in rails. So I had to include it with `gem 'actionpack-page_caching'`   after that it worked fine.